# Connect a button to bluetooth board and comunicate with Android

Tags: bluetooth, android

I want to create a small device, just a button that sends its status to an Android application through Bluetooth.

I bought a Bluno Beetle, but the information it exposes to Bluetooth cannot be modified from Arduino code, so I have no way to send the button status to the Android App, rookie mistake I guess.

Could you please tell me which model of arduino+bluetooth should I purchase to do this ?

Comment: buy a bluetooth button like this https://www.amazon.com/iBOLT-Bluetooth-distance-Customize-commands/dp/B00R3H4II8

Comment: "access features of compatible apps" seems suspicious, also I can´t find anywhere if it can be used on custom Apps.

Comment: it is unclear why the Bluno Beetle is unsuitable for your project .... please post the code that you tried .......... the Bluno Beetle is an arduino with a bluetooth module and you are asking about replacing it with another arduino and another bluetooth module

Comment: I connected a button to the Bluno Beetle and I want the Android App to know when the button is pushed and when is not. I can´t change the characteristic the Bluno Beetle exposes on the Bluetooth Service from the code, so I cannot send the button status to the Android App.

Comment: have you seen  this page? ... https://www.dfrobot.com/blog-283.html

Comment: Yes, what I am supposed to be missing ?

Comment: many different Bluetooth buttons are in shops.

Comment: The beetle supports both acting as HID device or as a serial interface. You can use both ways to interact with a button (though using as HID is better, because you can even control other apps with it).

Answer (score -1):

For your project you can buy cheap Arduino Nano, or even Mini(**programmer needed**). For BT module buy HM10. It's cheap and it supports Bluetooth Low Energy.

Comment: but that is exactly what Bluno Beetle is. a 328p plus CC2540

Comment: Why he asked then what he should buy

Comment: because he doesn't understand how it works

Comment: Hi Juraj, 

If you understand how it works, could you explain to me how can I get the status of a button connected to the bluno to an android app connected to the bluno by Bluetooth ?

Comment: @Grefu, you must use @ to get a user notified. the manufacturer has examples. jsotola posted a link in comments to  the question